# Star Wars Jedi Outcast, have 3 codes but main array is offline

Tags: star-wars-jedi-knight-2

I'm stuck at first level. I have three codes in datapad, but the main array is offline.

What did I miss?

Comment: Edit: Looking through a walkthrough on the level have you actually flipped the switch to turn the array on? There should be one in the red pathway which branches off the large T-Room.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the power switch is on the second floor.

There's some lift takes you to a control room. Then walk along the side arms

Comment: A screenshot would be appreciated.